# How to load vector map again onchanging dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jvectormap

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="getMap()">
      <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="SR">Serbia</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="map_vector">
```

Script to load map

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    getMap();
  });

  function getMap() {
    var focus = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var map = new jvm.Map({
      container: $('#map_vector'),    
      map: 'europe_mill',   
      focusOn: [focus]
    });
  }

</script>
```

I want to on change select menu to change focus and that's why I call function `getMap()` again onChange event , but map is not load again. I know I missing something big but I am not familiar with JS.

Comment: Every time I change select its just add new map with deferent focus, its not loading again same map.

Comment: You don't need to reload the whole map, just invoking `setFocus` will suffice. Please check the documentation for the `setFocus` method here: [jVectorMap Map](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/)